# How does a Benes network work?

Tags: networking, routing, algorithm

How does a Benes network work? If I have a Benes network with 8 nodes on each side, like this one here:

[image]

. . . **how do I know whether or not I take the upper or lower port of a switch in each stage**? For example, how would I get from node 001 (1) on the left side to node 111 (7) on the right side? Is there a general formula or something?

Thanks for any help clearing this up. It seems simple, but I just don't see it.